# Bypassing Review by Deleting Comment

Tags: bug, first-post-review

I was just reviewing this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10711917) in the First Posts queue. The answer needed a some formatting around the code blocks so I typed out a comment letting the user know, enabling the *I'm Done* button allowing me to proceed as normal.

Before proceeding, I deleted my comment as I was having some issues with formatting (*trying to put a back tick in a inline code block*) but was still able to proceed clicking the *I'm Done* button, even though, at that point, I hadn't *really* done anything as my comment had been deleted.

Is this by design or a bug? Should the *reviewed* status be reversed if the comment is deleted?

Comment: A user actually trying to abuse they system would always be able to delete the comment after completing the review, so you are actually preventing the abuse.  And there are plenty of other [easier] ways of abusing the review system if you're a robo reviewer (i.e. just "looks good"-ing everything that's not an audit.